# In doctrine what implications do 'relations:' have if the 2 relations are defined for two seperate column with a same table?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Suppose I have defined VendorClientLicense model like this:

```
VendorClientLicense:
  tableName: vendor_client_licenses
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    status:
      type: string(255)
      default: 'pending'
    client_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
    vendor_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: client_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: VendorClientLicenses
      foreignType: many
      owningSide: true
    sfGuardUser:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: vendor_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: VendorClientLicenses
      foreignType: many
      owningSide: true
  indexes:
    fk_vendor_client_licenses_sf_guard_user1:
      fields: [client_id]
    fk_vendor_client_licenses_sf_guard_user2:
      fields: [vendor_id]
  options:
    charset: utf8
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

If you see the two relations are defined with same name 'sfGuarduser'; What I have found for this in mysql is that in generated database **client_id** does not show any association with **sfGuardUser**, whereas **vendor_id** does! If I change it to '**sfGuardUser1**' and '**sfGuardUser2**' then shows both relationship! So I assume eventually this has important significance and should not be identical for a same model. Is there any other implications for it?

Plus can you name me a good schema generator like 'mysqlworkbenchdoctrineplugin' which handles situation like this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to name them differently.

I asked & received for the same problem here:

[MySQL: Two foreign keys in one table referring to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171687/mysql-two-foreign-keys-in-one-table-referring-to-another-table)

I haven't had any problems with it.

Regarding the plugin, sorry can't help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After going through your link another question came up in my mind. In this type of scenario 'foreignAlias' also needs to be defined differently. Think if I use the alias like: '$user->getVendorClientLicenses()', how it will decide which column to select for reference ( client_id or vendor_id )!

Comment: @medhad: exactly... you can define them according to how you'll need to refer to the relations from both ends.