# Multiple foreign keys to same table - Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, database-design, doctrine-orm

I'm currently moving a working time tracking application from pure php/js to Symfony with Doctrine2.
So far, everything worked fine. But before the weekend I stumbled across a problem with porting two tables to doctrine.

To be more precise:
Our employees' working time information comes from an external system. It records the employee's id, the current time and if it was the clock in or the clock out action.
Our application copies these information into it's own database and uses it to build accounting records for the employees. So, we have a structure as follows:

```
* Table originalStamps
    - Column id
    - Column employeesBadgeNumber
    - Column timeOfStamping
    - Column kindOfAction (coming or leaving)

* Table accountingRecords
    - Column employeesID
    - Column dateOfStanping
    - Column comingTime
    - Column leavingTIme
    - Column idClockingIn
    - Column idClockingOut
```

So as you can see, we reference to the originalStamps table twice. Either idClockingIn as idClockingOut may be null in case an employee forgets to clock in and/or out.

**And now for the actual problem:**
I cannot get Doctrine2 to create two foreign keys to the same table.
According to [MySQL: Two foreign keys in one table referring to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171687/mysql-two-foreign-keys-in-one-table-referring-to-another-table) it seemed to be possible in Doctrine1.
Do you know a way to make this work in Docrine2 again? Or should I rework my model for this particular case?

If you consider the relation to a clock in as well as to a clock out each as one to one relationship, I could simply introduce two new tables, comingTimes and leavingTimes. These could than be referenced by the accountingRecords table and would itself reference to the originalStamps table.

Any help and comments on which way to go? Looking longer for a solution to port the current structure to Doctrine2 as it is or reworking the model?

Thanks in advance
Faldon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my error.

So, the answer is, yes. Just create two ManyToOne relationships to the same entity.
I failed with it in the first place, because I inadvertently assigned the same name to the @JoinColumn definition for both entities.